# If variable (or element value) remains unchanged for over 2 seconds, do something?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a variable that auto increases up until a certain value. The value is determined based on an amount of elements on a page. Basically I count the amount of elements and for each element I find, I increase the value of the variable. The value of this variable is always different, sometimes it is 320, sometimes it is 512; it is random. But it increases from 0 to a certain number in a few seconds. Once it has stopped increasing, it will remain at that value and won't change any more
How can I detect if the value of this variable has remained unchanged for over 2 seconds? 
And if detecting a change in a variable is not doable, I can store the value in a hidden input field as well. Or in any other kind of field. I just need to be able to run a function when a value of a variable (or an element) has remained unchanged for over 2 seconds.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying all kinds of things for the past few hours with no luck.
EDIT:
Geez, no need to downvote, can a person not ask a question for help? :( I'm tired of trying myself and can't figure it out on my own. 
Anyway. Things I tried:

- Use a settimeout to see if I could get the previous value and compare it with the current, but didn't work out the way I thought it would
- Tried giving a certain value ("true") to another element once the last item was found, but the last item is always different and the function that increments the value is in a "while" within another "while" (it's difficult to explain why) so I can't really ever tell which item was counted last
- Tried duplicating the counting function and run it once in the beginning to know how many items there are (and store the value in a variable named "firstCounting"), then run the regular counting function again and as soon as the variable "count" from that function matched the value from "firstCounting", I'd know that I'd be at the end of the counting. But the function is so large and complicated that it'd be stupid to just copy it, only to see when the counter has stopped counting. My code is 474 lines long. I use it in combination with termsets and terms in SharePoint, but since the question is more JavaScript related, I posted it here.
- I tried event receivers, object watchers, anything that should "watch" a variable. Not even event receivers did the trick when I used a hidden input element instead of a variable.

Comment: Please show one of *all kinds of things you have tried* and we will try to help you. Like this it is a *give me teh codez* question.

Comment: You can check the value of the variable every 2 seconds using a simple setInterval, and take action if it hasn't changed in 2 consecutive checks.

Comment: @idmean I edited my question. I'm not your regular "give me the code" kind of person, just a simple hint in the right direction would've been appreciated too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this, I hope this is what you want

```
var someValue = 1
var prevVal = null;
var _myInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if(prevVal == someValue) {
        console.log("No change for 2 second", someValue)
    } else {
        console.log("Value was changed between past 2 second prev: ", prevVal, " New: ", someValue)
        prevVal = someValue;
    }
}, 2000)
```

**Edit**

Used `var` instead of `this`

**Check Image Attached for Output**
[image: Check Image Attached for Output]

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't knew about prevVal, you saved my day.

Comment: Actually this is pretty bad coding style. I would not recommend doing `this`
, since this will point to `window` so you will set a global variable.

Comment: @idmean
OK, thanks for pointing it, will it be OK if I actually use a global var, in that case we will be aware of that?

Comment: I would recommend using `null` as default for `preVal` as it was made to represent and unknown or missing value. (And it is cheaper than an (empty) string)